# Use of "Regarding to" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "Regarding to" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The secondary flow loss is due to.....
>
> Regarding to this kind of loss will be also discussed more in details
>   latter.

Comment: In 90% of the cases, "regarding"

Comment: You're probably mixing "regarding" and "in regard to". I would generally advise you to avoid both of these phrases at the beginning of a sentence. "This kind of loss will also be discussed in more detail later."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't say "regarding to"; the to is unnecessary and ungrammatical.
You say "Regarding this kind of loss.... Moreover, you use the phrase "in detail", not in details. So the sentence should be phrased as follows:

Regarding this kind of loss, it will also be discussed more in detail later (on).

The use of "latter' in the OP's sentence is also incorrect. The latter doesn't convey the sense that fits in the context and it is not an adverb. We need to use the adverb later; it means some time in the future or after the time we are speaking.